ocean animation not working
i watched a few tutorials for this and i can't understand what i'm missing out. they just type "#frame/50" or any number and then just press play and their ocean is oceaning, but nothing happens to mine



Did you bake the actions?

thanks, had no idea about that, i just tried and it's still not working, i'll just leave it motionless:)

Did you keyframe it?

Could you give a little more detail in your above post about your problem? I've done the ocean simulation before and didn't have a problem, but I don't remember all the steps. Check out this tutorial: https://youtu.be/p03fspwMY64

To fix the ocean, open the Driver Editor by right-clicking on the Time input and selecting Driver Editor from the drop down. Remove the hashtag (#) from the script. Also, you can remove Input Variables if you don't need them.


worked fine for me.  here's driver with "#frame/50":

